# how to implement vertical scroll in scroll view in android

Tags: android

I want to scroll a page using the following code. I am not getting where i am wrong. I am using this piece of code

```
scroll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    scroll.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            scroll.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

        }
    });



when i run this code it is not scrolling
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
scroll.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                /*
                                 * Scrolling to bottom every time when new
                                 * element is created
                                 */
                                scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                            }
                        });
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: i want to scroll down automatically on run time.

Comment: plz help me out on auto scroll down in this code its not working

Comment: did you see this links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080402/android-scrollview-force-to-bottom , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224761/android-scrollview-autoscrolling-as-text-is-added , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307267/how-to-scroll-to-bottom-in-a-scrollview-on-activity-startup they may help you to :)

Comment: after using PostDelayed it scroll but scroll vry fast and go to the bottom of the list. i want to scroll slowly and continuously. plz help me out on that. i want to make a notice board type which is scrolling continuously and smothly.